# how to sum each file by the same variable name in R

Tags: r

let's say I have Group1, Group2, … Group10. Each group has two columns- "calories"(numerical), and "Description".

how can I extract the total of calories for each group?

I'm trying this code but "SUM" function doesn't seem to work

```
    for (i in (1:10)){
    Group_names_calories<-c(paste(paste("Group",sep = "", 1:10),sep="",          "$calories")) # to get this epression "Group1$calories".... "Group10$calories"
    calories_by_group<- assign(Group_names_calories[i],
    sum(Group_names_calories[[i]]))
     }
```

Error in sum(Group_names_calories[i]) : 
  invalid 'type' (character) of argument

Answer (score 1):

At a first glance, you are calling `sum()` on your variable names not on the variable itself.

Also, manually creating a character vector of `"Group1$calories",Group2$calories",Group3$calories",Group4$calories",Group5$calories",Group6$calories",Group7$calories",Group8$calories",Group9$calories", Group10$calories"` I am afraid that won't help you with the intended sum of each variable/ column that I guess you are looking for. Could `colSums()` help you?

Still, you would need to demonstrate what your data subject is in your example. The `Group_names_calories` is just a string. Do you have any data? Could you post it here to help others help you?

Comment: thanks for your insights. I had the same opinion, but I hoped that R would transfer the names into variables once it's in the function.
Will try the colSums and let you know, if doesn't help, will post the data too.

Comment: - Group1
                   Calories   Description
      meal1     177          150g oats +200ml milk
      snack1     20          50g yogurt
      meal2     600          baked beans
      snack2    200         1pc crumpet

- Group 2
      meal1     400   250g oats 
      snack1     120           fruits
      meal2     600           300g chicken soup
      snack2    200         1pc crumpet


Im sorry trying to share the data in a list format but when I post the comment, it all becomes a text

Comment: It makes sense if you're a new user here. This may be of help when posting questions. At least it helped myself in my first ones. Give it a try: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @LilitGriggsAtoyan Perhaps at least a snapshot of your dataset would help others understand your data. Unfortunately, the answer to your question fully depends on what structure your dataset has i.e. is it a dataframe? A list of dataframes?

Comment: thanks @Khourdos, ill have a look at the link. Anyway, I asked my professor, and he said it is ok to combine al the groups in one data frame, so I just did that and used the group_by function. THanks for your help. Will read that link on how to ask a question :)

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have a dataframe called "df"

```
Group Cal
1     100
2     98
3     102
1     103
2     101
3     99
```

dplyr library can help you to group and summarize values in your dataframe.

```
install.packages("dplyr") # if you don't have dplyr installed
library(dplyr)
target <- df %>% group_by(Group) %>% summarize(sum=sum(Cal))

Output:
target
Group Cal
1     202
2     199
3     201
```

Comment: Thanks @NAN, eventually I did this option although I asked my professor, and he gave a hint how to do the other way, I thought this was much easier